# How may I change permissions on files that starts with digits?

Tags: bash, scripting, permissions

I want to change permission on files that starts with the digits 1 through to 9 (e.g. `1.txt`, `2.txt` etc.)

My code looks like this:

```
    #!/bin/bash
for(( i = 1 ; i < 10; i++))     
do

for file in /home/vs                   
do
if[ "$file" == "$i" ];                 
then

chmod +456 $file


done                             
done
```

but it doesn't work, I don't know where my mistake is.

Comment: the filename is more than just a number

Comment: `456` is rather unusual, you're sure you want this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code contains a few syntactical issues relating to whitespaces, and there is an `if` statement with a missing `fi`.

If you intend to set the numerical permissions `456` on all files in the directory `/home/vs` whose names start with any of the digits 1 through to 9, then you may do like so:

```bash
for (( i=1; i<=9; ++i )); do
    chmod 456 /home/vs/"$i"*
done
```

This may cause `chmod` to complain if there are no files starting with a particular digit.  It's therefore more common to loop over the names that we know exist with

```bash
for pathname in /home/vs/[1-9]*; do
    chmod 456 "$pathname"
done
```

You may shorten this to the single command

```bash
chmod 456 /home/vs/[1-9]*
```

which would call `chmod` with all files with names starting with any of the digits 1 through to 9 under `/home/vs`.  This would however fail if there are many thousands of such files (the command would be too large to execute, use the loop in that case).

If you want to restrict the matching of filenames to only files with a `.txt` filename suffix, then use `[1-9]*.txt` in the command above.  This would match filenames such as `1.txt`, `2.txt`, `3 good friends.txt`, `100 billion humans.txt`, etc.